# .NET 4.0 Interop string

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I am using DLLImport to load some functions into C# from my unmanaged DLL, and am using `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` for the strings.

When I compile project with .NET 3.5, the strings look fine. However, when I compile with .NET 4.0, my strings would appear to have the wrong charset.

What is happening?

Comment: Can you show the C# of the imported method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem that you're seeing is, however - keep in mind that the default for C# and Visual Basic is already `CharSet.Ansi` and the default for C++ is `CharSet.None`, which is equivalent to `CharSet.Ansi`. So your declaration is unnecessary.

Maybe try it without explicitly defining a CharSet, and see what that does.

You could also try `CharSet.Auto`, which will try to automatically select the correct character set